# Cx_oracle arrays with python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I’m working with an oracle database , using python.

I’m working with oracle type arrays (oracle 11.2) , when I query them into python using cx_oracle , I need to use the aslist method to make them useable . Sadly this process is longer then my project needs (3.5 seconds for 50,000 rows)

I’ve tried Converting it within the query and not within python using table() and listagg, but that resulted in a slower query and I’ve earned nothing.

I’ve also tried vectorizing a converting function on numpy , which still didn’t add any performance .

I thought about using cython , but I don’t have any idea how to use it while importing a different library , also jit from numba only slowed me down

Any ideas?

```
Data = cursor.fetchall()
modi_data = [row.aslist for row in Data]
```

Numpy version

```
Def convert(x):
    Return x.aslist

Data = np.array(list(cursor.fetchall()))
Vector = np.vectorize(convert)
Modi = vector(Data)
```

Comment: I doubt it's the python part, that's that slow -- it's the communication with oracle db.

Comment: @Daniel I’ve tested it , fetching the data takes time , but that’s not something I can control , the 3.5 seconds is process time of the data in python , after receiving it from the data base

Comment: Which bit is slow - the fetching or conversion?  You didn't say whether you were using arraysize to tune the fetching.  For 50K rows you would definitely want to bump the size.  https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.arraysize

Comment: @ChristopherJones conversion is slow , fetching is fine , anyway nothing I can do about fetching, I’m processing it in chunks of 50,000 since this oracle arrays takes a giant amount of ram

Comment: Can you provide some additional details on the type of data you are fetching? Please provide the SQL to create the type and the table you are fetching from as well as a script to generate the data you are fetching. With that I should be able to diagnose the cause of this issue for you.